# Access VBA SQL Case Code

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, case

IM trying to find an assigned item by serial number and if found, changes the table record's first and last name(of person it is assigned to) to storage and print out an error message uf ut doesnt. It also needs to work with all the quotes in VBA syntax which it isnt for me. The code is messy

```
strSQL = "SELECT FirstName,LastName Case [serialnumber] WHEN serialnumber = '& s' & _
"THEN FirstName = 'Storage' AND LastName = Null ELSE 'Record Not Found!'" & _
"FROM [Trial Invetory]"
```

s is a variable where user input is stored

```
s = InputBox("Enter Unit Serial Number", "Add unit to storage", Default)
```

Comment: Is this connecting to a SQL server backend or an Access table?

Comment: @KevenDenen Access Table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access supports [IIF function](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php), which can be used inside SQL query.

```
strSQL = "SELECT IIF([serialnumber]='& s','Storage', 'Record Not Found!') AS FirstName, IIF([serialnumber]='& s', NULL, LastName)" & vbcr & _
"FROM [Trial Invetory]"
```

Answer (score 1):

Access doesn't support case statements. Check out the IIf function for similar functionality in Access.

Comment: I was surprised why they were using it instead of case. Thanks